# Koin Dependency Injection switching between local and remote data source

Tags: android, dependency-injection, local-storage, repository-pattern, koin

So I am writing this app with remote data source. And I wanted to add local db storage capabilities. I have setup an architecture whereby I have an interface `DataSource`. A `RemoteDataSource` and a `LocalDataSource` classes implement that interface. The `RemoteDataSource` is injected with `ApiInterface` retrofit and the `LocalDataSource` is injected with DAOs.

Now there is this repository interface and implementation `SomeDataRepository` and `SomeDataRepositoryImpl`. If I want the repository to be able to fetch the data from api and save it to the database, how do I go about doing that?

Currently I have injected both `RemoteDataSource` and `LocalDataSource` classes to the `SomeDataRepositoryImpl` to access methods from different data sourcces. This way I can call something like `localDataSource.saveToDb()` and/or `remoteDatSource.fetchSomeData()` int `SomeRepositoryImpl` class. But I do not know if passing concrete implementations to a class is the way to go.

But if I pass lets say a single `DataSource` interface to the `SomeDataRepository`, I will have to define a `saveToDb()` function int the interface `DataSource` and then I will have to implement that in `RemoteDataSource` as well which is not that good.

Can anyone please guide me through what the best approach is to this solution.

And also while I am at it, is it any good to wrap the data with `LiveData` wrapper class right in the api interface for retrofit? cause I dont think when a method is called on the repository, I would want to observe it right there in the repo and then access the data to put it onto local db.

Comment: You should use 2 Interface instead of only one DataSource. I recommend you create RemoteDataSource, LocalDataSource interface and impl by RemoteDataSourceImpl and LocalDataSourceImpl. Inside SomeDataRepositoryImpl pass 2 instance of its

Comment: https://developer.android.com/jetpack/docs/guide#cache-data read more here, WebService is your RemoteDataSource and UserCache is LocalDataSource

Comment: @CôngHải Hi Thank you for your suggestion. And how about if I am to apply some logic like if the api request succeeds, save to db and then get from db. if it fails, get from db directly. and if get from db fails, then only show the errors. Can this be done all inside the repository class. Or is this too much for repository responsibility?

Comment: By what logic do you want to decide whether to use the local vs remote data source?

Comment: @MatthewPope I want to use local data source only if network request fails. Is that possible ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you want to have the local data source act as a fallback for the remote data source, you can create another data source implementation that is a [composition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object_composition) of the local and remote data sources. This composite data source can contain the fallback logic and handle the [delegation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Delegation_pattern) to the remote and local datasources as needed. Once you have done this, it is a simple matter to create a Koin module to construct these, and bind the composite data source to the data source interface.

Suppose this is your interface and the two data sources you already have:

```kotlin
interface DataSource {
    fun getData(): Data
}

class RemoteDataSource : DataSource {
    // ...
}

class LocalDataSource : DataSource {
    // ...
}
```

Then you can create a third implementation like this one:

```kotlin
class CompositeDataSource(
    val remote: RemoteDataSource, 
    val local: LocalDataSource
) : DataSource {
    override fun getData() : Data {
        return try {
            remote.getData()
        } catch (e: Exception) {
            local.getData()
        }
    }
}
```

To define all of this, your koin module would look something like this

```kotlin
module {
    single { RemoteDataSource() }
    single { LocalDataSource() }
    single<DataSource> { CompositeDataSource(remote = get(), local = get()) }
}
```

---

**Edit:** If what you actually want is a cache, you can use the local data source as your cache like this:

```kotlin
class CompositeDataSource(
    val remote: RemoteDataSource, 
    val local: LocalDataSource
) : DataSource {
    override fun getData() : Data {
        return try {
            remote.getData().also { local.saveData(it) }
        } catch (e: Exception) {
            local.getData()
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi there, this is really interesting and beautiful solution. Thank you for your answer. I will try this out. Could you also tell me how I can manage saving data whenever network requests succeed. Like where do I put the code that says if network request succeed save the data, so that if the network request does not succeed, the composite data source is able to return data from local db.

Comment: Assuming your data source API has a write method, then in your composite data store implementation, you could save to both the remote and local data source. But then you also need to decide what to do if you need to save something and the remote data store isn’t available. If you aren’t already locked in to a particular backend, you might want to look at using something like Couch DB or AWS AppSync that are designed for handling online and offline use cases. They may be able to handle some of this complexity for you, simplifying your application.

Comment: My use-case is such that I do not have an option to save data to the remote source. I just wanted offline storage so that if the remote source does not give me what I am looking for, the local db could provide the data that was saved last when the network request succeeded.

Comment: Sounds like you actually want is a *cache* in front of the remote data store. I’ll update my answer to explain that also.

Comment: Yes thank you. this is exactly what I was looking for. :)

Answer (score 2):

You can try the next approch, it requirs minimal changes and it works for me:

*Add interfaces for the remote and local data source, it should inherit the main DataSource interface*

```
interface QuotesDataSource {

fun getQuotes(skip: Int = 0, force: Boolean = false): Flow<List<Quote>>

suspend fun updateQuotes(quotes: List<Quote>)
}

interface QuotesRemoteDataSource : QuotesDataSource

interface QuotesLocalDataSource : QuotesDataSource
```

*Then use those interfaces to create koin module*

```
val repoModule = module {
  single { QuotesApi() }
  single<QuotesLocalDataSource> { QuotesDatabase(get()) }
  single<QuotesRemoteDataSource> { QuotesRemote(get()) }
  single<QuotesDataSource> {
      QuotesRepository(
          local = get<QuotesLocalDataSource>(),
          remote = get<QuotesRemoteDataSource>()
      )
  }
}
```